# add logos to tableview swift and arrange displayed array according to the suggested miles

Tags: swift, google-maps, uitableview

here are the codes. They get the atm locations from google places and display on a tableview.

```
     /**
 Calculates the distance between the user and a given location
 - Parameters:
 - location: ATM location coordinate
 */
func calculateDistance(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> String {

    let distanceLocation = CLLocation(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)

    var distance = self.lastLocation!.distance(from: distanceLocation)

    let locationInFoot = distance * 3.28084

    var locationString = String(format: "%d ft", Int(locationInFoot))

    if locationInFoot > 656.168 {
        // Over 200ft
        distance = distance / 1609.34

        locationString =  String(format: "%.01f miles", distance)
       }

       return locationString

       }

    class PlacesAPIManager : NSObject {

static let instance = PlacesAPIManager()
var session = URLSession.shared

/**
 Used to trigger the Google Places API Request
 - parameters:
 - completion : Array of ATM objects
 */


    func determineAtmsNearby(completion : @escaping ([ATM]) -> Void){

       let placesSearchComponent = NSURLComponents()
        placesSearchComponent.scheme = "https"
       placesSearchComponent.host = Constants.basePlacesURL
       placesSearchComponent.path = "/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json"

       // Build the query items for the api request
    let radiusQueryItem = URLQueryItem(name: "radius", value: "20000")
    let typeQueryItem = URLQueryItem(name: "type", value: "atm")
    let apiQueryItem = URLQueryItem(name: "key", value: 
     Constants.APIKey)
    let location = URLQueryItem(name: "location", value: 
    LocationManager.instance.getCoordinateString())


    placesSearchComponent.queryItems = [radiusQueryItem, typeQueryItem, apiQueryItem, location]

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: placesSearchComponent.url!,cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { 
      (data, response, error) -> Void in

        var places : [ATM] = []

        if let data = data,

            let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSDictionary {

            let results = json?.object(forKey: "results") as? NSArray

            for place in results! {

                do {
                    let place = try ATM(atmDictionary: place as! NSDictionary)
                    places.append(place)
                } catch {
                    completion([])
                }
            }
            completion(places)
        }

    }).resume()

}
```

}

ATM CLASS

```
    class ATM : NSObject, MKAnnotation {

let title : String?
let latitude : Double
let longitude : Double
var subtitle : String?
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

init(atmDictionary : NSDictionary)throws{

    // Error handling
    guard let name = atmDictionary["name"] as? String else {
        throw SerializationError.missing("name")
    }
    guard let geometry = atmDictionary["geometry"] as? NSDictionary else {
        throw SerializationError.missing("gemoetry")
    }
    guard let location = geometry["location"] as? NSDictionary else {
        throw SerializationError.missing("location")
    }
    guard let latitude = location["lat"] as? Double else {
        throw SerializationError.missing("latitude")
    }
    guard let longitude = location["lng"] as? Double else {
        throw SerializationError.missing("longitude")
    }

    // Initialise Properties
    self.title = name
    self.longitude = longitude
    self.latitude = latitude
    self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.latitude, longitude: self.longitude)

    // Initially this is not calculated
    self.subtitle = "N/L"

}

/**
 Used to update the Atm object with the distance from the user as the value for 'subtitle' property
 - parameters:
 - coordinate : Coordinate
 */
    func updateAtmLocation(coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D){
    self.subtitle = 
    LocationManager.instance.calculateDistance(location: coordinate)
      }

       }
```

ATM LIST CLASS

```
      class AtmList: NSObject {

static let instance = AtmList()

var atms : [ATM] = []

func addAtm(atm : ATM){
    atms.append(atm)
}

func resetAtmList(){
    atms = []
}

func getAtmsCount() -> Int{
    return atms.count
}

func udpateAtms(index : Int, coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D){
    atms[index].updateAtmLocation(coordinate: coordinate)
}
```

}

I have two questions:

1. I would like to arrange the display from the lowest distance to the highest
2. I would like to get the logo of each bank and display it by the side of each name on the tableview list.

Comment: Please add codes to the question.

Comment: Don't use screenshots. Past code inside your question. Also paste code for ATM and Bank class.

Comment: the codes are in now @ata

Comment: done, check for codes now @ZassX

Answer (score 0):

**1.)**

Inside ATM class, I would create a new property which will represent distance - each time you are calculating distance, also update that property. This will enable you to sort your array of ATMs by distance.

After appending the ATMs to the array, you can use something like this to sort the array:

`places = places.sort({$0.distance < $1.distance})`

**2.)**

Please provide more information about bank: do you have custom object for that, do you have image / image url?

Comment: I have images in my assets and the banks are of the list of Atms. So I want for every ATM associated with a bank name to have the logo beside it on the view.

Comment: You will have so somehow associate ATM to the bank. Does API return any data that could be useful in this case? Can you provide API result for lets say one ATM? In case it doesn't I am afraid you are stuck.